# opening files from a website

Tags: python

I asked a similar question yesterday but I included some code that basically took my question on a different tangent than I had intended.  So I shall try again.

I am rewriting a python script that crawls a website to find a few hundred text files, I have no interest in any content of the text file beyond the second line of the file.  Previously I would download all of the files then loop through them all to extract the second line.  I would now like to open each file as my script discovers it, grab the second line, and close it without downloading to my harddrive then opening it.

So basically is there a way I can open a file that is at www.example.com/123456.txt and take the second line from that file copy it to an array or something without downloading it and then opening it.

Comment: No I am aware of that, opening the file into memory then discarding it sounds about right

Comment: Since `urlopen` returns a file-like obejct, you may be able to simply use `readline` twice, which may avoid downloading the entire file (depending on buffering). Would probably save some transfer with large files, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) to just get the file contents into memory, extract the second line, and then immediately discard the file from memory, if you wanted, without ever hitting your disk.

You *are* going to have to download the contents over the internet, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like `urllib2.urlopen('url').read().splitlines()[1]` but I guess that would download the entire file to memory

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve the fist N lines (or perform a line seek) but if the web server supports the [`Range`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00#section-3.1) header you could retrieve the first N bytes of the file (byte seek).

If you know the maximum length of a line, you could do this:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> maxlinelength = 127 # nb: in terms of bytes
>>> myHeaders = {'Range':'bytes=0-'+str(maxlinelength)} # from byte 0 to maxlinelength
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://www.constitution.org/gr/pericles_funeral_oration.txt', headers=myHeaders)
>>> partial = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> partial.readline() # first line discarded
>>> yourvar = partial.readline()
>>> yourvar # this is the second line:
'from Thucydides (c.460/455-399 BCE), \r\r\n'
```